# FATAL EXCEPTION: main- I have no idea what's wrong

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-manifest, android-activity

I'm still fairly new to Eclipse and I have tried everything to keep these errors from happening:

```
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission       Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx   cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster } from ProcessRecord{4157fb20   20520:com.mshaw.avanos/10174} (pid=20520, uid=10174) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1332)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1286)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1691)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1505)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3244)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3351)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at com.mshaw.avanos.AvanosActivity.onClick(AvanosActivity.java:34)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4894)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-30 00:38:28.773: E/AndroidRuntime(20520):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The first error really interests me as I have already provided a permission. Here's my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mshaw.avanos"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE_CALL"  />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/avanos_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".AvanosActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />L
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Password" 
        android:label="@string/settings">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the part of my main activity that's causing this whole mess:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private Button button1;
private EditText editText1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setEditText1((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1));
    button1.setOnClickListener(this); {}}

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                EditText num=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String number = "tel:" +num.getText().toString().trim();
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: what is this **button1.setOnClickListener(this); {}}** ?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment seeing as this really isnt an answer but in the future you should probably set android:debuggable:"TRUE"

Answer (score 6):

There is no permission like

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE_CALL"  />`

**Replace** that with

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"  />`

Here is the list for your reference : [Manifest.permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)